# добавить новую строку только если ключи уникальны

Tags: postgresql

есть одна таблица, в которой два столбца взаимно уникальны.

как написать sql-запрос, который добавляет в таблицу новую пару значений, если такой пары нет?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В синтаксисе INSERT Statement имеется ON CONFLICT clause.